# Configuring Facebook Webhooks to get notifications in Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I am trying to configure my Laravel app to receive notifications for any comments given on my Facebook page.
I have verified the Webhooks with my Laravel app and now am trying to subscribe to a sample endpoint as mentioned in this link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/subscriptions-edge

I am sending the cURL request as mentioned in the document but I am getting the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) The parameter object is required.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "Apj143rwxNgw6TF3xUWQvZ9"
  }
}
```

Also I am not aware of what the access token in the cURL request is supposed to be.
The format of the request is as follows :

```
curl -X POST 
     -F "object=user" \
     -F "callback_url=callback_url" \
     -F "fields=photos" \
     -F "verify_token=verify_token" \
     -F "access_token=access_token" \
     "https://graph.facebook.com/app_id/subscriptions"
```

Am not sure if am missing something or am totally looking in the wrong place. Any help will be appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Only difference to their example I can see, is that you have added `-X POST`. Try without that, `-F` already forces POST, and Content-Type multipart/formdata. Not sure if the `-X` option might overwrite the latter.

Comment: When I removed -X POST it gives me another error. It does not identify what type of reuqest am trying to send.